# Request headers (and cookies sent) missing in Chrome Network Inspector?

Tags: http-headers, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector, request-headers

I've noticed that request headers and cookies sent have disappear from network inspection in some cases (XHR request for example), at least with OSX Google Chrome.

If you don't see what I mean, just open the web inspector and connect to your Twitter account, then check the XHR requests: you can see request payload and response headers but headers and cookies sent have disappear.

Any idea how to fix this ? I've tried activating some exotic flags in about:flags but saw no changes.

Comment: Did you upgrade chrome recently?

Comment: Tried it on the main channel chrome and on the dev channel chrome, both are up to date yes (OSX Mountain Lion).

Comment: I know they introduced a lot of other little tabs to help filter request types. If I  had my mac here I would check for you though, unfortunately on windows machine :(

Comment: Same issue here. Might https have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be because the requested page is loaded over https. I don't know why Chrome suddenly finds it necessary to hide the request headers, but testing, a secure connection seems to be the trigger for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that request cookies are shown in another tab named 'cookies', it seems to set-cookie header is somehow cut from 'headers' tab.